# Android Pay Development setup

Tags: android

I wasn't able to find this anywhere, especially not on Google.

I am working on an Android app and I need to implement Android Pay, so users from US (or wherever Android Pay is supported) can run payments. The problem is that I am not in US, and even more so, I am from a country where even PayPal is not supported.

I managed to install Android Pay on a smartphone with no sim card, but I am unable to add a credit card (not even the one from US).

Is there any way I can make Android Pay work during development phase? I don't really care for the production environment as long as I am able to test couple of payments during development, but from the looks of it, I will be unable to even add a card, let alone, develop anything related to Android Pay.

Is anyone else having these issues, and in case you have them solved, how did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am mentioning following  steps these may be useful for you.

Step 1:- If you are not in us and you want to use android pay then you should have a us registered email id (You can make us email id with help of gmail ) then you can download android pay .

Step2: You can register you credit card in android pay now a days few credit cards are supported by android pay you can try with Visa, Master Card, American Express cards and  other cards which support the android pay.

Step 3: Implement following points https://developers.google.com/android-pay/diagrams .

If you have some problem then comment me.